# PL/SQL compilation error while creating package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a new package, but I get the `ORA-24344: success with compilation error` and I cannot figure out what is the problem.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY lucratori_pack AS
    CURSOR disp_lucrator RETURN LucratorRecType IS
SELECT ID_LUCRATOR, NUME_LUCRATOR, PRENUME_LUCRATOR, SALARIUL FROM LUCRATORI ORDER BY SALARIUL;

PROCEDURE increase_sal(
     emp_id LUCRATORI.ID_LUCRATOR%type,
     emp_inc_sal LUCRATORI.SALARIUL%type
)

IS
    emp_new_sal LUCRATORI.SALARIUL%type;
BEGIN
    UPDATE LUCRATORI
    SET SALARIUL = SALARIUL + emp_inc_sal
    WHERE LUCRATORI.id_lucrator = emp_id
    returning SALARIUL INTO emp_new_sal;
END increase_sal;


PROCEDURE getAllEmps 
IS

CURSOR c is 
    SELECT NUME_LUCRATOR, PRENUME_LUCRATOR FROM LUCRATORI;
c_nume LUCRATORI.NUME_LUCRATOR%type;
c_prenume LUCRATORI.PRENUME_LUCRATOR%type;

BEGIN
    open c;
    loop
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        fetch c INTO c_nume, c_prenume;
        dbms_output.put_line('Numele: ' || c_nume || ' Prenumele: ' || c_prenume);
    end loop;

    close c; 
END getAllEmps;

END lucratori_pack;
```

I have tested the procedures, and they do not contain errors. Below is the code for the table I am using in the 2 procedures declared inside the package:

```
CREATE TABLE Lucratori (
id_lucrator varchar2(5) constraint pk_lucrator primary key,
nume_lucrator varchar2(30),
prenume_lucrator varchar2(30),
data_nasterii date,
    salariul number(5),
    pozitia_ocupata varchar2(40),
    id_companie varchar2(5),
    constraint fk_lucrator_companie foreign key (id_companie) 
references Companii(id_companie)
);
```

Comment: What does `show errors` give you?

Comment: how can I run show errors in apex?

Comment: I added it before the end package, and after the end package and still see only `ORA-24344: success with compilation error`

Comment: Try to run it in SQLPlus, then you'll be able to `show errors`. Also is the header compiled?

Comment: Try to CREATE or REPLACE first the Package specification for you procedure "increase_sal" before you create the body.

Comment: I have already created the package specification

Comment: Pease try to run it in SQLPLus and post the result of `show errors`

Comment: I am installing it now

Comment: If you are going to be developing PL/SQL code professionally, you seriously need some tools that at least tell you what the compilation errors are. You can't post everything you write on SO and hope people point things out for you.

Comment: For the record, you could also use the SQL interface within Apex to query USER_ERRORS

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's the wrong place for a cursor definition, the place just after `PACKAGE BODY` definition , where some global parameters may be defined. And, that cursor (disp_lucrator) is used nowhere. Then Just remove that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE lucratori_pack AS
 PROCEDURE increase_sal(emp_id     LUCRATORI.ID_LUCRATOR%type,
                       emp_inc_sal LUCRATORI.SALARIUL%type);
 PROCEDURE getAllEmps;

END lucratori_pack;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY lucratori_pack AS
/*  CURSOR disp_lucrator RETURN LucratorRecType IS 
    SELECT ID_LUCRATOR, NUME_LUCRATOR, PRENUME_LUCRATOR, SALARIUL FROM LUCRATORI ORDER BY SALARIUL;*/
PROCEDURE increase_sal(
     emp_id LUCRATORI.ID_LUCRATOR%type,
     emp_inc_sal LUCRATORI.SALARIUL%type
)
IS
    emp_new_sal LUCRATORI.SALARIUL%type;
BEGIN
    UPDATE LUCRATORI
    SET SALARIUL = SALARIUL + emp_inc_sal
    WHERE LUCRATORI.id_lucrator = emp_id
    returning SALARIUL INTO emp_new_sal;
END increase_sal;


PROCEDURE getAllEmps
IS

CURSOR c is
    SELECT NUME_LUCRATOR, PRENUME_LUCRATOR FROM LUCRATORI;
    c_nume LUCRATORI.NUME_LUCRATOR%type;
    c_prenume LUCRATORI.PRENUME_LUCRATOR%type;

BEGIN
    open c;
    loop
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        fetch c INTO c_nume, c_prenume;
        dbms_output.put_line('Numele: ' || c_nume || ' Prenumele: ' || c_prenume);
    end loop;

    close c;
END getAllEmps;

END lucratori_pack;
/
```